# Graph theory and homology group

Tags: graph-theory, homology-cohomology, planar-graphs

If I obtain a graph from an associative array and from this graph I obtain the homology group, what considerations can I make on the associative array from the homology group obtained from the graph?

Comment: I don't know what an associative array is, but the "homology group" of a graph is not going to be very interesting: it can be calculated just from the number of vertices, edges, and components of that graph. (Unless you have an embedding on a surface, as the [tag:planar-graphs] tag seems to indicate, but in that case you should give a lot more detail, and I kind of suspect that you don't actually want that tag.)

Comment: @Misha Lavrov - thank you for answer. Yes, I am interested also in embedded graph. If graph is embedded on a plane and it has homology group H equal to H_0=Z and H_2=Z2 what we can say about associative array or about the graph?